# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem “railties” for Rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, railtie

I am trying to upgrade to Rails 4.0.0, and I changed the gem versions of `sass-rails` and `coffee-rails`. I need to resolve this gem conflict between `rails` and `coffee-rails` before I can upgrade to Rails 4.

When I ran `bundle update` this is the output I got:

```
$ bundle update
Updating git://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme.git
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies..............
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.0.0) ruby

    coffee-rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.0.rc2)
```

My `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'cancan'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'devise', '~> 1.5.3'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'haml'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.4'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.0'
gem 'simple_datatables'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'

gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'noty-rails'

gem 'font-awesome-rails'

gem 'socket.io-rails'

gem 'attr_encrypted'

gem 'bullet', :group => 'development'

#temp for demo.managetherapy.com
#gem 'faker'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
#  gem 'faker'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.7.0'
  gem 'webrat'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'hpricot'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
  #gem 'web-app-theme', '~> 0.8.0'
  gem 'web-app-theme', :git =>'git://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme.git'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'compass-rails', '1.0.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 2.1.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
#gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'

gem 'passenger'
```

Answer (score 72):

Also `bundle update` only allows you to update one gem at a time, which is hard if you are updating to `Rails 4` and a whole lot of gems have to be updated at the same time.

I solved this by deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and doing `bundle install`.

This is of course assuming you have no conflicting explicit gem version in your `Gemfile` to start with. So if this fails, remove version numbers from the Gemfile.

Comment: This works for me. Delete `Gemfile.lock` and everything is as smooth as hell :D.

Comment: This worked for me: I must add, that also, if one gem in specific is causing issues, change the ~> for >= (ex. gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0' for gem 'coffee-rails', '>= 4.0.0') and follow nathanvda steps

Comment: The `~>` will update, but only patchlevel (so according to semver: only non-breaking changes). Changing to `>=` will update to the latest version (taking all other dependencies/constraints into account), and actually just states a minimal version that is needed (from your end). So yes: that is probably most definitely needed.

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me as well. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Did NOT work for me, I found ExReanimator's answer worked for me

Comment: Well this answer is not a psychic, I have you have explicit versions in your `Gemfile`, and they conflict, you will have to remove the explicit gem version. I will extend my answer accordingly. Main thing, for me, was to delete the `Gemfile.lock`, otherwise I was never able to update.  So if you started with ExReanimators answer, it would not have worked unless you deleted the Gemfile.lock. But happy you got it to work.

Answer (score 28):

Just remove gem versions (coffee-rails and sass-rails) from Gemfile and run **bundle update**

Answer (score 12):

Run `gem update rails` first, then `bundle update`

Comment: Should the bundle update automatically update the rails gem that is found in the Gemfile? Is there a need to run gem update rails manually?

Comment: gem update rails worked for me when updating to Rails 6

Answer (score 9):

You have an outdated version of Devise, use Rails 4 compatible

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.0.0.rc'
```

Also change `coffee-rails` to

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

and try doing

```
bundle update coffee-rails
```

Answer (score 7):

You have gems that aren't supported by Rails 4. Comment out all the gems except for Rails 4 and uncomment them one at a time after running bundle install to find the culprits. You might need to undo some of your version locks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete the `Gemfile.lock` file
2. refer [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4?view=asciicast) for basic gemfile changes
3. run `bundle install`

Everything will work fine. :)