# Rails: Can't include scss in rails 4.1.1. - TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

Edit: The solution was to lock sass-rails gem to 4.0.2 version.

---

I have a wierd problem this afternoon.
I was trying to implement a bootstrap theme (Detail admin) but when included in application.css.scss I got an error:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in C:/sites/busapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

I tried changinh extension of my file to only .css or only .scss but it didn't work. I'm now trying 2h30min so I'm getting desperate and asking if someone else knows how to solve this.

```
OS: Windows 8.1 64bit
Ruby 1.9.3p545
Rails 4-1.1
```

My gemfile:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

#====Custom gems====
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rails_debug'
  # gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'letter_opener'
end

#Database
gem 'pg'
#Slim
gem 'slim'
gem 'slim-rails'
#Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
#Authentication
gem 'devise'
#Other
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'

# gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
# gem 'enumerations'
# gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
# gem 'acts_as_simple_translatable'
# gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
# gem 'active_model_serializers'
# gem 'font-awesome-sass'
# gem 'apipie-rails'
# gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.9'
# gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.1.2'
# gem 'bazaar', '0.0.2'
# gem 'memoist', '0.9.1'
```

Application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "neki";
```

application.html.slim

```
 doctype html
html
  head
    title Busapp
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  body
    = link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "btn"
      | Logout
    = render "layouts/flash"
    = yield
```

Also, when I remove only the last file from application.css.scss I don't get an error. And it's not due to file being corrupt because I've tried with multiple ones and in this one is only body backround color set to red.

Another thing that might be relevant is what happens when I run bundle update: http://prntscr.com/4i0xfl

Edit: Even when I try to add something like this directly to my .css.scss it still breaks.

```
body {background-color: red;}
```

Comment: changing the gem file version didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know for sure, but will just update previous wrong answer with various suggestions which maybe already where tried:

1)
Found this similar issue: [github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3093](http://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3093) where the solution was to update some gems

2)
And based on the provided output of the screenshot found this: [github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/540](http://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/540)   where the solution was to precompile the assets (namely bootstrap).. looks like it's a sprocket bug.

3)
And for the railties-dependency error various approaches on SO: [stackoverflow.com/questions/17327953/rails-4-0-0-bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-railties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327953/rails-4-0-0-bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-railties)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what did you mean by this. 
Here is my file structure: http://prntscr.com/4i1ov9

I've tried adding to my application.css.scss following but none of the options worked:
    -@import "neki.css.scss";
or
    -@import "neki.css";
or
    -@import "neki.scss";
or the same with stylesheet path in front:
for example: 
    -@import "stlesheets/neki.css.scss"; 
ofc. i did it without - in front, its just to avoid mentioning users

Comment: It's ok, maybe I also misunderstood the question - have you added something from the new theme inside the application.css.scss and it worked before with your settings or is the application.css.scss newly added? And how/where do you currently include/import this file?

Comment: First of all, thanks for trying to help me.
First i had only -@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
-@import "bootstrap"; and later when I try to import any other .css.scss to application.css.scss it breaks.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, will delete or adjust the answer in case this works - have you already checked this similar issue..? https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3093  (at bottom of this page some gem install update recommendations); don't know if this works for you and maybe you already tried that..

Comment: And 2nd guess.. https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/540 where the solution was to precompile the assets (namely bootstrap).. looks like it's a sprocket bug.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. The solution was to lock sass-rails gem to 4.0.2 version. Seems like it was uncompatible with something else, I dont' know with what but it works. :)
Edit: Sorry I can't upvote your answer beacuse I need at least 15 reputation.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you and that I was able to give some support though not knowing for sure :) Seems like there're diff solutions working for diff settings. And don't mind about the upvote, wouldn't deserve it. Enjoy your new theme ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've already solved the problem, but I struggled with this problem yesterday and came upon a decent solution (workaround?), so I wanted to share it.

I'm running Rails 4.1.1 on Windows 7.

I would get an ExecJS Runtime Error with the bootstrap-sass gem, but not with twitter-bootstrap gem (no preprocessor).

Quick 2-step workaround.

1. Rename application.css.scss --> application.css
2. create a new file custom.css.scss to hold the code that was previously in application.css.scss

Problem Solved!

Source:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-custom_css

Comment: using require_tree is not good style, as you should import them explicitly. That requires application.css to be scss. However, the new sprockets now wants all .css.scss files to be named .scss. require self is also not good style.